# Navigation controls outside the carousel - Zurb Foundation Orbit

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am trying to have the Navigation controls just outside the carousel instead of default inside.

There's no data-option available for this. So I tried hacking the CSS for the nav arrows to give it negative absolute positioning.

However, the parent container is set to overflow: hidden and hides the arrows. 
Is this possible by default?

Comment: Post your site example or code example

Comment: It is the default foundation Orbit carousel. The arrows are inside, you can see it here

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Currently, it is positioned inside the container. 
I wish to have it positioned outside.

So it would be 

left arrow -- container with carousel -- right arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loooking at your example I was able to apply the following CSS to the ul with the id of #featured1:

```
#featured1 {
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Doing so you will need to move the timer in the upper right over a bit and also throw off the caption width. That is easily done with this css:

```
.orbit-container .orbit-timer {
    right:70px;
}

.orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * .orbit-caption {
     width:90%;
}
```

This solution will make your slider images smaller so you may want to increase the width of .large-10 for this case.